# BigDecimal Constructor not accepting supported method signature

Tags: groovy, bigdecimal

I'm seeking clarification as to why this doesn't work:

`BigDecimal zeroValue = BigDecimal(0).setScale(4,RoundingMode.HALF_UP)`

With exception:

`groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.BigDecimal() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [0]`

And this does:

`BigDecimal zeroValue = ((BigDecimal)(0)).setScale(4,RoundingMode.HALF_UP)`

Documentation indicates it should work as a constructor which returns the object upon which additional operations can be carried out.

```
public BigDecimal(int val)
Translates an int into a BigDecimal. The scale of the BigDecimal is zero.
Parameters:
val - int value to be converted to BigDecimal.
```

SetScale also returns the BigDecimal objects once computed:

`public BigDecimal setScale(int newScale,RoundingMode roundingMode)`

Thank you for clarification.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `new` keyword to call constructor? `BigDecimal zeroValue = new BigDecimal(0).setScale(4, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);`

Comment: BigDecimal(0) doesn't call a constructor in Java, new BigDecimal(0) does

Comment: Also there is a static constant for 0 and you can access it using `BigDecimal.ZERO`

Comment: Also, you are not using `BigDecimal` as it's part of Java... You are using another implementation of the concept... -> `org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.BigDecimal()`

Comment: I'm curious how you're running this... Is it plain groovy? Or a script evaluated using groovyshell... or using Java scripting engine? The default `BigDecimal` imported in Groovy is `java.math.BigDecimal`, and that's the class of decimal literals.

Comment: Yup, of all the mistakes I could have done, I missed the new keyword.  @ernest_k It's calling groovyshell I believe through anypoint studio.